# Android Security: values.xml under res(generated) folder

Tags: android, firebase, google-api

I am just curious to know about the file `values.xml` under the folder `res(generated)/values`. This file contains the firebase database URL, google API key etc information. Will it cause any security issue to the app? Can anybody access the firebase database using these values by decompiling the apk? Screenshot of the file is attached.

[image: Screenshot of values.xml]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a file **`key.properties`** in your root directory with the values for different secret keys:

```
 GOOGLE_KEY="1234567890";  //Example
```

Then

```
def apikeyFile = rootProject.file("key.properties")
def apikey = new Properties()
apikey.load(new FileInputStream(apikeyFile))
 
android {

  defaultConfig {
     
    buildConfigField("String", "GOOGLE_KEY", apikey['GOOGLE_KEY'])
  }
}
```

You can now access these  field anywhere within your source code with the BuildConfig object provided by Gradle:

```
String googleKey = BuildConfig.GOOGLE_KEY;
val googleKey    = BuildConfig.GOOGLE_KEY  //KOTLIN
```

FYI

Make sure to exclude the file from being checked in by adding to your **`.gitignore`** file:

```
key.properties
```

Comment: Although the code and guidance provided is great, it does not answer the question. Does exposing your Api ID and Api Secret pose a security concern?